# ess-rdired: I get this error "no ESS process is associated with this buffer now"

Tags: r, emacs, ess

To use `ess-rdired` to browse objects, I followed the ESS manual and added the following to my `.emacs`:

```
(autoload 'ess-rdired "ess-rdired"
  "View *R* objects in a dired-like buffer." t)
```

When I do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ess-rdired`, a buffer listing the objects in your current environment appears.

However, when I press shortcuts like <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> I get this error:

> "no ESS process is associated with this buffer now."

Besides, can `ess-rdired` update info of objects when they are changed?

Comment: this is a known issue, at least in relation to Sweave. I believe (but am not certain) that it is fixed in the development version. The workaround I currently use is to use `C-c C-s` and associate the buffer with a running R process. Hope this helps

Comment: @richiemorrisroe, your method works after adding (setq-default ess-dialect "R"). Thanks. However, this problem seems not common. Is it because most people do not use it to manage workspace at all?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and sure enough C-c C-s solves it. I added the following function to my dot emacs file to automate this. I mapped the function to C-c o which will load rdired or refresh it. Any improvements would be very welcome!

```
(defun ess-R-show-objects ()
  "Calls rdired and associates with R process"
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "*R*") ;;Only run if R is running
      (progn
        (ess-rdired)
        (ess-rdired-switch-process))
    (message "No R process")
    )
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-co") 'ess-R-show-objects)
```